# No detection of Windows 7 installed already

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows-7

When I am trying to boot my PC with Ubuntu via bootable USB, it says it doesn't detect any OS installed and asks to install it on whole hard disk. I want to install it along side my Windows 7 OS.

Boot info [**here**](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1219930).

Answer (score 1):

choose manual option, and then you can choose the partiton on which you want to install.

Or simply use wubi.exe to install easily like software installation inside windows.

Answer (score 0):

You have overlapping partitions.

1. Backup your documents
2. via [Gparted](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GParted), delete the sda3, sda5, sda6, sda7 partitions
3. retry the Ubuntu installation